# How to use individual term frequeny features with Naive Bayes classifier?

Tags: python, nlp, text-classification, naivebayes, countvectorizer

I am currently working on a NLP task with Naive Bayes classifier.

My features consist out of bigrams and unigrams.

Now, to fit X_train I want to merge the top 100 unigrams and the top 50 bigrams.

How do i do that?

I only can use either top 100 unigrams or top 50 bigrams.

Is there a smart way, without exporting the grams, to include the merged 150 grams?

```
cv = CountVectorizer(strip_accents='ascii', analyzer='word',                                                          token_pattern=u'(?ui)\\b\\w*[a-z]+\\w*\\b',                                
                      lowercase=True, stop_words='english',   
                     ngram_range=(1,1), max_features=100)                                              
X_train_cv = cv.fit_transform(X_train)                                                           
X_test_cv  = cv.transform(X_test)
```

Sure i can use `ngram_range(1,2) = 150`  but that is not the same as `ngram_range(1,1), max_features=100` and `ngram_range=(2,2) , max_features=50`

Comment: can't you just use `ngram_range(1,2)` (using both unigram and bigram) and then take the top 100 only by weight?

Comment: yeah, but the problem with that is that the bigrams have obviously a much lower weight than the unigrams. if i use range(1,2) only 5 bigrams are considered. Thats why I want to merge them seperately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One could create 2 separate Vectorizers and merge them using feature union: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html

Comment: i will try that asap. thanks four your effort.

Comment: thanks you. exactly what I was looking for :)